# How to use binary strings in Elixir NIF

Tags: elixir, erlang-nif

How do I get the `char*` data from an `ERL_NIF_TERM` coming from an Elixir binary string?

I see [`term_to_binary/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1) function but it does not seem to be the right thing.

Comment: term_to_binary is binary encoding of elixir structure, it has nothing to do with strings. Your best bet is to read nif documentation: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html

Answer (score 0):

As it’s stated in [`NIF` documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html)

> Terms of type binary are accessed with the help of struct type [`ErlNifBinary`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#ErlNifBinary), which contains a pointer (`data`) to the raw binary data and the length (`size`) of the data in bytes. Both data and size are read-only and are only to be written using calls to API functions. Instances of `ErlNifBinary` are, however, always allocated by the user (usually as local variables).

That said, your `NIF` function should have a signature alongside

```c
static ERL_NIF_TERM
foo(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
```

where `argc` is supposed to be `1`, `argv[0]` would be a constant pointer to `ErlNifBinary` and the respective [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) call would be like

```elixir
def foo(binary), do: :erlang.nif_error("Load NIF!")
```

Answer (score 0):

While using NIF, you have to use *charlist* and **NOT Elixir binary Strings**. Use `to_charlist/1` function to convert binary string to charlist and then call the NIF function.

In the NIF function, you can read charlist like so,

```
#define MAXBUFLEN 1024

char src[MAXBUFLEN];
enif_get_string(env, argv[0], src, MAXBUFLEN, ERL_NIF_LATIN1);
```

`src` now holds the string value.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to prepare `ErlNifBinary` and then populate it using `enif_inspect_binary()`.

According to [NIF doc](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html), `ErlNifBinary` is a struct with two visible fields like below.

```c
typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    unsigned char* data;
} ErlNifBinary;
```

`data` is the `char*` you want. `enif_inspect_binary()` fills `ErlNifBinary` with information about the binary, making its data accessible.

Assuming that the binary string is the first argument of your nif function, the C code should look something like this.

```c
static ERL_NIF_TERM
do_stuff_with_binary(ErlNifEnv *env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[]) {
    unsigned char data[100];
    ErlNifBinary bin;
    if (!enif_inspect_binary(env, argv[0], &bin)) {
        return enif_make_atom(env, "error");
    }
    // Do stuff with binary. Its data is now accessible via bin.data
    // memcpy(data, bin.data, 100);
    
    return enif_make_atom(env, "ok");
}
```